# msys2 (msys64) cannot find -lcrypt

Tags: msys2

I have msys2 (msys64) https://www.msys2.org/ and am compiling some older code in gcc, but get "cannot find -lcrypt", -lcrypt is declared in the makefile, as crypt is cited in the code.

The only version of crypt library I can get to get to run is -lcrypt32 which is a library in msys2, but this doesn't seem to offer the support for crypt so I then get crypt errors. Does anyone know how to get the normal crypt recognized in msys2? I assume it's relying on mingw, I also recall from a long while back that mingw doesn't support lcrypt, but I could be wrong.

> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/6.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/bin/ld: cannot find -lcrypt
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>   make: *** [Makefile:260: arch] Error 1

Answer (score 3):

MSYS2 does not appear to ship a MinGW version of libcrypt. But as long as you just want to run this locally and do not need to redistribute it, you could compile it with the MSYS2 GCC. There is libcrypt for it. Just run...

```
pacman -S msys/libcrypt-devel
```

And then that should work:

```
gcc test.c -lcrypt
```